# Creating new pages automatically depending on the div number

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating and appending new `divs` with template literals. However I want it to create a 'next page' when x number of `divs` appended. Is there a way to do that in HTML & JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are u trying to create a PDF or something?

Comment: Yeah, the easiest thing u can do is keep track of the number of divs u are appending. then use `appendchild` to add a new wrapper.

Comment: It's a blockchain nft displayer kind of webpage i'm trying to create. You never know how many nfts they have.

Comment: can u share some code, u've worked on in a stackblitz?

Comment: It's nothing too special, html has a couple of empty `divs`. JS query the data from the blockchain, and the template literal part is; [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cd6xis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do that is creating `iframe` tag and set your html as `src` attribute by `encodeURI` like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '<div>put some div here</div>';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```